# Testing out Ubuntu via USB - hanging

Tags: 12.04

I wanted to test out Ubuntu via USB. I loaded it on and got to the screen where it asked me whether I wanted to install it on my computer or just test it out using the USB. When I say I want to test it out, it takes me to a black screen and it just hangs with a curser line showing but I can't type anything.

Any ideas on what is wrong?

Comment: Its probably a graphics card problem.  What graphics card do you have?

Comment: What happens if you test the same USB drive on a different computer?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple possibilities:

1. The Graphic Card is not support or not compatible.
2. The files in the USB are maybe missing.

If you haven't already, try making the USB flash drive with [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).

[image: unetbootin]

UNetbootin allows you to create bootable Live USB drives for Ubuntu, Fedora, and other Linux distributions without burning a CD. It runs on Windows, Linux, and Mac OS X.